# Does ios 11 sdk update may have affected the exist Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

Our company's ios application is based on Objective-C. 
Apple announces that any app updates they submit will have to be built using the ios 11 SDK.

Does the XCode/SDK update affect the Objective-C support?
Can we continue to develop the exist Objective-C project using new ios 11 SDK?

Comment: *"Does the XCode/SDK update affect the Objective-C support?"* - No; *"Can we continue to develop the exist Objective-C project using new ios 11 SDK?" - Yes

Comment: Yes, it only affect swift old syntax code. For Objective-C you will not face any issue, but for safe side you can try to only upload app (NOT FOR REVIEW) on itunes, if any issue will their it will give error or warning.

Comment: Except issues with deprecated (well removed essentially) methods/frameworks, it should be transparent. Objective-C is a stable language.